# HTC Desire HD Crash on Photo click

Tags: camera, htc-desire-hd, crashes

Not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question.

My phone crashes every time I try to take a picture with 20-30% battery.

I have tried with Low and Mid quality picture (1-3 MB) but this didn't help.

Phone Details:

- HTC Desire HD
- Android Version: 2.3.5
- HTC Sense version: 3.0
- Software Number: 3.13.110.4
- Kernal: 2.6.35.10
- Browser Version: Webkit/533.1
- SD Card: 8 GB (Available: 5GB)

Hope this info helps. Let me know if any one need any more details.

Comment: Are you really sure it only happens when your battery is at 20-30%? What about below 20 or above 30%. That seems strange to me, crashes shouldn't be related to the power source at all (at least they should occur unspecific if the battery is half dead). Does it not happen when you charge it? If yes, replace your battery and see if it helps. Maybe shooting photos draws more current than your broken battery can supply and your phone crashes due to a brownout.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the app data or cache? Force stop? Restart the phone?

Comment: ce4 - Yes it only happens when battery is left this much. Works fine when on charging.

Comment: @AlEverett- Yes tried clearing App data and cache both. No Force stop. And ofcourse phone get restarted automatically when it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the battery and updated to 4.1 and all is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

My desire HD too.

I just presumed that if the battery was too low and it tried to use flash, then it used too much power from the battery and turned off.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about using the flash.